# Universal localization argument for polynomially bounded functions of a stochastic proceess

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

As in many mathematical disciplines, many statements about stochastic processes are really easy to prove for bounded objects (sets, function, processes, etc.). This is why many proofs (e.g. for Ito's formula, Dynkin's Formula, Feynman-Kac Equations, Burkholder-Davis-Gundy Inequality) employ a localization argument, where the process in question is replaced by its stopped version, that stops as soon as it gets larger than a certain bound.

When I try to prove my own statements that seem intuitively true even for unbounded objects, I often get stuck and cannot finish without boundedness...

It turns out, that the intuition was not too wrong, but lacked three characterizations: The functions I imagined, which were unbounded but seemed to work where all *polynomially bounded*:

$$ f(x) \le C(1+|x|^p) , \text{ for some } C>0 \text{ and } p>0 \tag{1}$$

And the process' running absolute maximum had a *finite $p$-th moment*

$$\mathbb E(\sup_{s\le t}|X_s|^p) <\infty \text{ for all } t, \tag{2}$$

(if $X$ is a martingale, this is implied by finiteness of $\mathbb E(|X_t|^p)$, via Doob's inequality, or of $\mathbb E([X]_t^{p/2})$, by the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy Inequality.)

and was *locally bounded*, i.e. there exists a sequence stopping time $\tau_n$ with limit $$\tau_n\rightarrow\infty \tag{3},$$such that the stopped processes $X^{\tau_n}$ are bounded. This is true e.g. for all *continuous processes* or processes with bounded jumps. In this case $\tau_n$ is given by $\inf\{t:|X_t|\ge n\}$.

**Lemma 1** If the above three assumptions hold, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E\left(f(X^{\tau_n}_t)\right) = \mathbb E\left(f(X_t)\right).$$

*Proof:* Due to (1), the sequence $f(X^{\tau_n}_t)$ is bounded by $C(1+|X^{\tau_n}_t|^p)$ $\le C(1+\sup_{s\le t}|X_s|^p)$, which is integrable due to (2). As (3) implies pointwise convergence to $f(X_t)$ the assertion follows from the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

**My question**

Is the above correct and are there deeper or more general results in this direction you could point me to? E.g. what about processes with unbounded jumps or sufficient conditions for (2)?